# Better way to read a line of user input in zsh? (e.g. with zle?)

Tags: zsh

Zsh's `read` for some reason is echo'ing `^M`'s instead of accepting them as `<Enter>` keystrokes. (If `-d` is set, then they are recognized as `<Enter>`'s, but still echoed.) It also doesn't support basics like the backspace key.

I can get around this by hacking / running `bash`,

```
> a=$(bash -c 'read -e -p "What would you like to do?: " tmp; echo $tmp')
What would you like to do?: eat cake
> echo $a                                                                
eat cake
```

but I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way.

Comment: Cannot confirm on a fresh `zsh` 4.3.10 install; `% read a` works fine here.

Comment: This is using iterm on OS X; `read` does work on Linux machines.

Answer (score 36):

To input a line of text comfortably under zsh, use [`vared`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-vared). Using `vared` instead of `read` invokes [zle](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html), which is the equivalent of passing `-e` in bash to invoke readline.

```
vared -p 'What would you like to do?: ' -c tmp
```

---

The behavior you describe with plain `read` looks like a misconfigured terminal rather than a shell issue. Run `stty -a` to show your terminal settings, and make sure that `eol` is set to `^M` and `erase` is set to what your <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key sends. Depending on the operating system and how it's set up and on the terminal, <kbd>Backspace</kbd> sends either `^H` or `^?`. The backspace setting usually goes wrong because of some configuration file that tries to set it manually, so the first thing you should do is track and remove any such misconfiguration. If you find none, review your terminal emulator's settings to check that it isn't set into some historical compatibility mode. If all else fails, add something like this to your `~/.zshrc`:

```
if [[ $(ps -o comm= $PPID) = iterm ]]; then
  stty erase '^?'
fi
```

Comment: vared -p 'What would you like to do?: ' -c tmp

Comment: So cool! Didn't know about the `vared` builtin. Turns out, `zshzle` man page is definitely worth at least skimming through.