# Read plaintext input from inside ZLE widget

Tags: shell, script, zsh

I want to read normal text input (a.k.a. not the regular ZSH editor that might have auto-completion etc.) from inside a ZLE widget. Currently when I try:

```bsh
function myfunc() {
    echo -n "Your name: "
    read -re 
    echo $REPLY
}

zle -N mywidget myfunc
bindkey "\C-k" mywidget
```

When I call `myfunc`, everything goes as expected but when I press `C-k` (binded to the keystroke through `bindkey` above) it's like the read command is skipped:

[image]

I haven't pressed enter, just `C-k` one time.

What I want is to have bash-like functionality and wait for my input.

I'm aware of [zsh read input in zle widget](https://superuser.com/questions/1045605/zsh-read-input-in-zle-widget) but I don't want to use ZSH's minibuffer editor as it has autocompletion etc. and this [Better way to read a line of user input in zsh? (e.g. with zle?)](https://superuser.com/questions/427645/better-way-to-read-a-line-of-user-input-in-zsh-e-g-with-zle) solution didn't work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ZLE redirects the input to the functions to `/dev/null`, as described in the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zshzle):

> The standard input of the function is closed to prevent external commands from unintentionally blocking ZLE by reading from the terminal

Thus the input should be read from the tty directly, as follows:

```bsh
function myfunc() {
    zle -I
    echo -n "Your name: "
    read -re < /dev/tty
    echo $REPLY
}

zle -N mywidget myfunc
bindkey "\C-k" mywidget
```

To print text correctly while inside the widget `zle -I` is prepended, as described in the man page as well:

> If the handler produces output to the terminal, it should call 'zle -I' before doing so (see below). The handler should not attempt to read from the terminal.